# What should I add in my views.py if I want to accept complaints from different users in my complaint management system in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am making a complaint management system where different users can log in and add complaints to the system. I need to make a page where the user can add complaints that will be saved in the admin panel but idk how to do it. I have created the model and the template but idk what else to add in the views or the forms. I've tried a bunch of different things but none seem to work. can someone please tell me how to do it?

Models.py:

```
class Complaints(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   description = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
   highpriority = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents')

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

Template:

```
<div class="col-lg middle middle-complaint-con">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open fa-4x comp-folder-icon"></i>
        <h1 class="all-comp">New Complaint</h1>

        <form class="" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="email" class="form-control col-lg-10 comp-title-field" placeholder="Complain title">
            <p class="desc">Description</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary preview-btn">Preview</button>
            <textarea class="form-control comp-textarea" rows="7" placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
            <button type="file" name="myfile" class="btn btn-secondary attach-btn"><i class="fas fa-file-upload"></i> Attachment</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary save-btn" value="submit"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save</button>
        </form>

    </div>
```

It needs to look like this:
[image]

Please help me with this... I've been at this the whole day and Idk what else to do so figured might as well just ask here.

Comment: First switch your models.Models to admin.Models, if you want it on the admin display. Second could you just save the complaints as an object?

Comment: Yeah, I can save it as an object but will it still show up in the admin panel?

Comment: well you also have to regiester the model as well.

Comment: example admin.site.register(Complaints)

Comment: It should then show up in you admin panel

Comment: I did do that but i don't know how to save those inputs by the users into that model

Comment: are they showing up in your admin now?

Comment: the complaints is showing up in the admin panel but idk what to write in the views to make the users complaints to get saved in it

Comment: well if you make it an object you can just use the .save() build in function.

Comment: `def newcomplaint(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ComplaintForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'forms':form}
    return render(request, 'new.html', context)`   -> this is what I typed in my views.... will this work? or do I need to add something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect but worked for me with very basic model form:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ComplaintForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
      instance = form.save(commit=False)
      instance.user = request.user
      instance.save()
    else:
      form = ComplaintForm()
```

Also, you may need to authenticate the user with [login_](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/) decorator or [is_authenticated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) method as well as validate the input data.

Some useful links:

- [Django Forms Validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/)
- [Render Django Form Manually](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html)